# spring boot application deployed but i am getting 404 error even after all setups done

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

https://i.stack.imgur.com/midVJ.png
Marked the embedded servlet container as provided in you pom.xml
marked the embedded servlet container as provided
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbKsJ.png
Update packaging to war
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEzuD.png
run war file in apache tomcat 10 web app folder
**I am getting an error even after running all above code...can anyone help me**

Comment: i am using tomcat 10 , intellij , spring boot , java, resources with above code

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Don't post code/config as images, or even worse, links to images. Post them as code. Also "just" marking it a war doesn't deploy it you need to take some additional steps. Finally Tomcat10 isn't (yet) supported as that is JakarteEE which is scheduled for Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3, so you need Tomcat9.